# program returning garbage values even after declaring variables in c

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

**how do i correct this**

> i didn't use structure intentionally
>   this is a program to input student's name, subject and marks.
>   in the last block, the array (subject+f) 's 1st subscript is returning garbage values while the rest subscript are returning desired result.
>   i have also posted the image of output as link.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()

{

int size,i,k,sub,a=0,reference;


    int temp,sorted;
    char temp_s[10];
    char temp_sb[10];

    printf("enter the size of class\n");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    printf("how many subjects are there?\n");
    scanf("%d",&sub);
    reference = sub;
    char name[size][20];
    char subject[size*sub][20];
    int marks[sub*size];
    int total,subtotal,retotal;
    for(k=0;k<sub;k++)
    {
    printf("so what's  the no. %d subject\n",k+1);
    scanf(" %s",(subject[k]));
    }

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {

            int j,k=0;
            printf("Enter a name of student %d\n",i+1);
            scanf(" %s",(name+i));


                for(j=a;j<reference;j++)
                {
                    printf("enter marks of %s\n",(subject[k]));
                    scanf("%d",(marks+j));
                    k++;
                }

                a=j;
                reference=sub+j;


        }

    reference=sub;
    a=0;


    printf("\n list of students and marks:\n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            int j,f=0;
            printf("%s\n",(name+i));
            for(j=a;j<reference;j++)
            {
                 printf("%s %d\n",(subject[f]),(marks[j]));
                 f++;
            }
            a=j;
            reference=sub+j;

        }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you take a debugger and step thru the program. There is definitely something wrong with your indexes.

Comment: Is any student or subject name more than nine characters?

Comment: Why don't you use subject[f]? I think subject is a char** and you want to have a char*... The two dimensional array is a Pointer to a Pointer. While you want to write in a char*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you also need to change

```
int marks[sub];
```

to

```
int marks[size * sub];
```

one mark for each subject for each student, correct?

Comment: it works now , but the code
`for(j=a;j<reference;j++)
                {
                    printf("enter marks of %s\n",(subject[k]));
                    scanf("%d",(marks+j));
                    k++;
                }` 
returns one extra loop when i take subject and size more than 2.

Comment: can you update the question with your current complete code?

Comment: i updated it. it works fine as long as i not enter the size more than 2.

Comment: add this debug statement just before you prompt for the marks and I think you will see what is going on `printf("%d..%d\n", j, reference);`

Comment: thankyou. the problem was with `reference=reference + j;` . so i changed it to `reference=sub+j`

Comment: Exactly !!  Good job figuring it out.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the problem with length of names and subjects, this here is a major problem:

```
(subject+k)
```

You are probably misunderstanding the `subject[k]` and `*(subject + k)` equivalent.

The variable `subject` is an array of arrays. That means `subject[i]` is an array (of `char` and can be used as a zero-terminated string).

The expression `(subject + k)` is a pointer to the array in `subject[k]`. It's equal to `&subject[k]` which have the type `char (*)[10]`. It's can not be used as a zero-terminated string without dereferencing. So either use `*(subject + k)` or the simple, less-to-write and easier-to-read `subject[k]`.

Comment: i understand but it doesnt seem to have any difference to the result.. though i corrected it.